# What is the relation between a bifurcation in a dynamic system and an explosive dynamic system (definition)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

What is the relation between a bifurcation in a dynamic system and an explosive dynamic system (definition) ? Is it the same?

Comment: As noted on your other question, *explosiveness* is not an established term. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by this.

Comment: Ok I will check in what sense the authors of the work I read use it, but frankly, I didn't understand how they meant it.